# Groups list does not appear in buddypress

Tags: buddypress

In my admin panel, when I go to Groups, it DOES NOT shows the groups list.
Though there are groups in the database.

buddypress :- version 2.0
BBpress :- Version 2.5.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a plugin confliction problem. I have de-activate some plugins and problem is solved.